# Asp.net core API method is called on fluent api validation failed

Tags: api, validation, asp.net-core, fluentvalidation, mediatr

I have implemented Fluent API validation with Aspnet Core and MediatR and disabled the default MVC validation.
Previously, On invalid data, the API validation will be called first and then API method will be called.

On invalid data, Fluent API Validation will throw an error and the call won't fired to the api method.

But now, even on invalid data, the api method is called.
what am I missing?

**Configuration:**

```
services.AddMvc().AddFluentValidation(fv =>
        {
            fv.RunDefaultMvcValidationAfterFluentValidationExecutes = false;
        });
        ValidatorOptions.Global.CascadeMode = CascadeMode.StopOnFirstFailure;
        services.AddValidatorsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

**Code:**

```
public class LoginCommandValidator : AbstractValidator<LoginCommand>
        {
            public LoginCommandValidator(IStringLocalizer<Resource> stringLocalizer)
            {
                this.CascadeMode = CascadeMode.StopOnFirstFailure;
    
                RuleFor(v => v.Username)
                    .NotEmpty().WithMessage(stringLocalizer["InvalidUsername"])
                    .NotNull().WithMessage(stringLocalizer["InvalidUsername"]);
    
                RuleFor(v=>v.Password)
                    .NotEmpty().WithMessage(stringLocalizer["InvalidPassword"])
                    .NotNull().WithMessage(stringLocalizer["InvalidPassword"]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?  Got the same issue.

Comment: I forgot what I have implemented. But I have fixed. I will check and get back to you. If you found, let us know too.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can write an ActionFilterAttribute, and then add this filter to your Controller.
Like this:

```
 public class ValidateModelStateFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (!actionContext.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreteErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, actionContext.ModelState);
        }
    }
}
```

Then add this filter above your controller:

```
[ValidateModelStateFilter]
```

Hope this can help you.